# How do we calculate the integral of measurable functions which are not Riemann integrable?

Tags: measure-theory, definition, lebesgue-integral, measurable-functions

To start with, let us consider the following

**Definition**

Let $f:\Omega\to\overline{\mathbb{R}}_{\geq0}$ be a nonnegative measurable function on $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mu)$. The integral of $f$ with respect to $\mu$, also denoted by $\int fd\mu$, is defined as
\begin{align*}
\int fd\mu = \lim_{n\to\infty}\int f_{n}d\mu
\end{align*}
where $\{f_{n}\}_{n\geq 1}$ is any sequence of nonnegative simple functions such that $f_{n}(\omega)\uparrow f(\omega)$ for all $\omega$.

**Definition**

Let $f$ be a real valued measurable function on a measure space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mu)$. Let $f^{+} = fI_{\{f\geq0\}}$ and $f^{-} = - fI_{\{f<0\}}$. The integral of $f$ with respect to $\mu$, denoted by$\int fd\mu$, is defined as
\begin{align*}
\int fd\mu = \int f^{+}d\mu - \int f^{-}d\mu
\end{align*}
provided that at least one of the integrals on the right side is finite.

Thus the problem to integrate a measurable function is reduced to calculate the integral of nonnegative measurable functions.

Moreover, we also have the following

**Theorem**

Let $f$ be a bounded function on a bounded interval $[a,b]$. Then $f$ is Riemann integrable on $[a,b]$ iff $f$ is continuous a.e. according to the Lebesgue measure $m$ on $[a,b]$. In this case, $f$ is Lebesgue integrable on $[a,b]$ and the Lebesgue integral $\int_{[a,b]}fdm$ equals the Riemann integral $\int_{[a,b]}f$, i.e., the two integrals coincide.

**My question**

In the case of Riemann integrable functions, one may apply the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus to calculate integrals, since antiderivatives and integration are strongly related.

My question is: how do we calculate the integral of measurable functions which are not Riemann integrable? Is there a routine method to do so other than the direct application of its definition?

I am new to measure theory, so any contribution is appreciated.

Comment: Monotone/dominated convergence theorems can help if you can suitably approximate by Riemann integrable functions.

Comment: This isn't really going to have a general answer.  It depends a lot on how the function is specified and what you know about it.  It's sort of like asking "how do you compute the order of a group"?

Comment: @csch2 thanks for the feedback!

Comment: @NateEldredge thanks for the comment! Could you please provide me a particular example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the book Brian S. Thomson, Judith B. Bruckner, Andrew M. Bruckner "REAL ANALYSIS"
Second Edition (2008) on page 360 there is following theorem:

If $f$ have bounded derivative on $[a,b]$, then for Lebesgue integral holds
$$f(b)-f(a) = \int\limits_{a}^{b}f^{'}d\lambda$$